# Adobe Flex using Eclipse helios IDE in Linux(ubuntu 11.04)

Tags: java, apache-flex, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-11.04

I am new to the flex development.i downloaded the flex4.6 sdk and i would like to write a simple application using flex .i already installed java 1.7. My environment details are 
IDE is eclipse (Helios)
OS is Linux(Ubuntu 11.04)
i tried with below links [Example1](http://www.seanhsmith.com/2010/03/29/flex-for-free-setting-up-the-flex-4-sdk-with-eclipse-ide/#related-posts) , [Example2](http://www.dotkam.com/2009/03/29/adobe-flex-in-ubuntu-develop-compile-and-run/) but i am unable to understand how those examples working.
please guide me or suggest any useful links for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Link](http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/05/install-flex-sdk-under-ubuntu-linux/) may be helpful to you.For mine its working fine, from your second example instead of

```
# flex SDK home
export FLEX_SDK_HOME=/opt/flex-sdk
alias mxmlc='/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -jar "$FLEX_SDK_HOME/lib/mxmlc.jar" +flexlib="$FLEX_SDK_HOME/frameworks" "$@"'
```

i am using

```
# Make the FLEX compiler available
export PATH=/home/thomas/Software/flex_sdk_4.5/bin:$PATH

# Export the LPS home directory
export LPS_HOME=/home/thomas/Software/OpenLaszlo/lps-root

# Make the LZX compiler available
export PATH=/home/thomas/Software/OpenLaszlo/lps/bin:$PATH
```